# Constructor syntax in return statement?

Tags: c++, constructor

I understand everything about the following code, except this line

```
A f(){return A(i);}
```

Specifically I don't understand the syntax `A(i)`. I know it returns a value of the type `A` but what does the `i` in the brackets mean?

Is it a constructor call with some variable?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace ::std;

class A{
    public:
        int j;
        A(int z){j = z;}
        int g(){return j;}
        int operator+(A a){return a.j + j;}
};
class B{
    public:
        int i;
        B(A a){i = a.j;}
        A f(){return A(i);} // ???
        A operator-(){return A(i);}
};
int main(){
    A a(1);
    B b = a;

    a.j = b.f() + a;
    b.i = a.g();
    a = -b;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`A(i)` is a functional cast expression. It's creating a temporary object `A` from `i`. The process will call the appropriate `A` constructor.

In C++ there is no way for the programmer to "call the constructor". What the programmer does is create objects at all sorts of places, and the construction is arranged automatically. A functional cast expression is one such way to create an object.

And mind you, that while this is formally "creating a temporary", copy elision (return value optimization) will actually make it initialize the return value directly.

Comment: "A functional cast expression is one such way [...]", could you name others? Anyway, +1, the precision of your answers is nothing but awesome.

Comment: @lubgr - Declarations, and new expressions to name a couple more. I think it's a bit of a tangent for this answer though. And thank you for your kind words!

Answer (score 2):

It creates an A, calling the constructor `A(int z)`.